# Flutter app bundle build error: "Could not find method keyAlias() for arguments"

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I'm trying to setup a test release version of a flutter application in Google Play store, but I'm getting the error `Could not find method keyAlias() for arguments` in `build.gradle` file when building the app bundle. The relevant part of the `/android/app/build.gradle` file where the error happens looks like:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

// ...

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias'],
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    }
}
```

and the `key.properties` file is:

```
storePassword=<some password here>
keyPassword=<another password here>
keyAlias=<some alias here>
storeFile=<absolute path to the key store>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. I've found the source of error, and I will answer my question here because I think it's a trap that any rookie can fall in.

The source of error is the comma at the end of the line defining the keyAlias.

The error message was totally misleading.